# Would it be illegal outside of Russia to do mess with and troll their government and officials?

Tags: russia, ukraine, war

EG black faxing their offices, catfishing governors and Duma members and judges to relieve them of their money, draining their bank accounts, causing general pandaemonium, etc, so as to be able to help Ukraine.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, many of the activities you describe ("draining their bank accounts") would come under the definition of fraud. Some countries are dragging their feet when it comes to the prosecution of computer fraud against victims abroad, but generally speaking, that is illegal. Others might come under various computer sabotage laws, while yet others ([catfishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catfishing) for emotional distress) may fall under stalking -- or be legal.

Your question seems to argue that the targets are "deserving victims" in some way, but most legal systems do not allow the perpetrator to make that decision.

One could also try to argue that cyberattacks are an act of war. International laws are still highly unsettled on that. If it was an act of war, it would not be for a private citizen to initiate it.

Comment: It's not under the idea of deserving victims so much but as a way to participate in a war that is already declared. Ukraine certainly declared war on Russia when the invasion commenced, so in at least that sense, the perpetrator is not making that decision and is just self mobilizing just as people did by sandbagging road barricades or demolishing bridges.

Comment: @R-Obsessive, most nations will get **really** upset if acts of war are perpetrated by their residents, from their territory, without government permission. If you want to help that way, go to Ukraine, apply for residency, join the armed forces.